# Promise.reject().catch(console.log) got an `Illegal invocation` on my Android 5.1 phone

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've try this on Chrome before and it works well, but on my Android 5.1 phone it got an `Illegal invocation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some browsers, console.log doesn't like being invoked in the global context. You can do one of these:

```
Promise.reject().then(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

or

```
Promise.reject().then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: And, this is the "safe" way to pass any method in any circumstance unless you know for sure that the method never uses `this` in its implementation.